# mac mysql fail to help add an environment variable

Tags: mysql, macos

Terminal:

```
mysql -uroot -p
zsh: command not found: mysql
➜  ~  echo $PATH
/Users/zhangzhenxing/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:B:A:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin

➜  ~  export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin

➜  ~  echo $PATH

/Users/zhangzhenxing/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:B:A:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin

➜  ~  mysql -uroot -p

Enter password:
```

Execution of `export PATH = $ PATH: / usr / local / bin: / usr / local / mysql / bin`, after restarting the terminal, mysql still can not start, the reason I ask that God horse,

You need to re-execute the source order?

Answer (score 1):

Try: `echo "export PATH=\$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin" >> ~/.zshrc`, then restart your terminal.

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to set the PATH environment variable when a new shell is started. This is typically done by editing your `~/.zshrc` file.